# LinkedIn JavaScript API causes double back button click in IE 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, api, internet-explorer, linkedin-api

Including the JavaScript script snippet and making an **IN.API.Raw** call causes IE 8 and 9 to add an extra page to their history. This means that on every page that the LinkedIn JS API is used, the back button has to be pressed twice to go back a page.

It looks as though the GET request from the IN.API.Raw call is causing IE to register a 200 code as a new page. Therefore adding a new page called "Processing" to the history. Does anyone know of any workarounds? It seems crazy that LinkedIn doesn't support IE 9 with their JS API.

I also don't want to go back to using the REST API as the OAuth expiry prevents it being a permanent solution to getting the number of followers for a company.

These are the scripts I'm using. A fairly standard Raw API call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: [API KEY HERE]
   onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
   authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.API.Raw("/companies/12345:(num-followers)")
      .result(function (result) {
         document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML = result.numFollowers;
       })
      .error(function (error) {
         alert("error: " + error.Message);
      });
   }
</script>
```